# django - get query range from url

Tags: python, django, get

I use python and django
I have this url

http://localhost:8000/index/price=100+-+100000

the range here is between 100 and 100000

how to get and work with this range in python?

Comment: Try to use `http://localhost:8000/index?low=100&high=100000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, normally, we don't do that (let user input the range in URL) we send it via Ajax in POST method.

And if you still want this, we have [URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/):

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

Some thing like this and you take it in Views.py

Comment: if you generated this must be JSON;
or you can get the URL via: url = window.location.href; and handle it by yoursefl